# visual-studio-code Terminal PATH clobbered with macports

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, macports

My VSCode terminal path for fish shell looks this:
`echo $PATH | tr ' ' '\n'`

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin
/usr/local/bin
/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin
/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin
/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin
/Library/Apple/usr/bin
/Users/viranchee/bin
/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin
/Library/Framewosudo
dscl
.
-delete
/Groups/macportsrks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin
```

while path at Terminal.app is

```
/Users/viranchee/bin
/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin
/usr/local/bin
/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin
/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin
/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin
/Library/Apple/usr/bin
```

The extra `decl -delete ..macports../python` path is present at all possible shells spawnable from VSCode as defaults

I also modified my config.fish to print the $PATH, after which my terminal at vscode start reads

```
START OF CONFIG.FISH, PATH before modifying:
/Users/viranchee/bin /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin /Library/Framewosudo dscl . -delete /Groups/macportsrks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin /usr/local/bin /System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /Library/Apple/usr/bin /var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin /var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin /var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin
END OF CONFIG.FISH
Welcome to fish, the friendly interactive shell
Type help for instructions on how to use fish
viranchee@PL- Viranchee  TWVM56G2D5 ~/.c/fish>
```

I had macports installed and then uninstalled it. I also removed brew. I also removed the "-l" shell argument to zsh and fish. Basically, all the shells $PATH is clobbered. I tested it by setting the default shell, quitting vscode and opening vscode again.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't see a "decl" in your output. I see a "dscl". what's up with that?